# Setting up 'encoding' in Python's gzip.open() doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, gzip

Even tho I tried to specify encoding in python's gzip.open(), it seems to be always using cp1252.py to encode the file's content.
My code:

```
with gzip.open('file.gz', 'rt', 'cp1250') as f:
    content = f.read()
```

Response:

> File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
>   return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position    52893: character maps to undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Python 3.x

`gzip.open` is [defined](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/gzip.html#gzip.open) as:

> gzip.open(filename, mode='rb', compresslevel=9, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None)

Therefore, `gzip.open('file.gz', 'rt', 'cp1250')` sends it these arguments:
- filename = 'file.gz'
- mode = 'rt'
- compresslevel = 'cp1250'

This is clearly wrong, because the intention is to use 'cp1250' encoding.
The `encoding` argument can either be sent as the fourth positional argument or as a keyword argument:

```
gzip.open('file.gz', 'rt', 5, 'cp1250')  # 4th positional argument

gzip.open('file.gz', 'rt', encoding='cp1250') # keyword argument
```

## Python 2.x

[Python 2 version of `gzip.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html#gzip.open) does not take the `encoding` argument and it does not accept text modes, so the decoding has to be done explicitly after reading the data:

```
with gzip.open('file.gz', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

decoded_data = data.decode('cp1250')
```

Comment: If you'd look closer on my interpreter's response you would see that I'm using Python 3.4 when your answer refers to Python 2.7

Comment: According to gzip.open() specification in the Python3 docs, it takes these arguments: gzip.open(filename, mode='rb', compresslevel=9, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None), and setting the mode to rt means you're getting the text, not the binary.

Comment: Why else would it use cp1252.py for anything when encoding bytes?